# How to trigger 'on' with AutoComplete JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI Autocomplete. It works fine as per the demo on the [JQuery UI webpage](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default)

The below only fires when I leave the control, where as I want the below to fire when I type or paste or choose from the drop down list

```
$("#addNewWebpageCategory").autocomplete({
    source: categories,
    minLength: 1,
    change: function (e, ui) {
        alert("a");
    }
});
```

I've also tried to swap `change` with `on` and this still doesn't do what I want.

As per this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/1544/), which has minor differences to the above snippet, if you type in the letter `a` I want the alert to show. However, it only shows after the focus is lost from the control

I know I can bind another event, such as adding an additional

```
$( "#addNewWebpageCategory" ).on( "autocompletesearch", function( event, ui ) {
    alert("aga");
});
```

However, my question is why do I need this additional event.

Comment: Per API Doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change: `change( event, ui ): Triggered when the field is blurred, if the value has changed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use `search` instead of `change`, according to http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search:

```
search( event, ui )
    Triggered before a search is performed, after minLength and delay are met. 
    If canceled, then no request will be started and no items suggested.
```